# Possible Research Topics for High School

Tags: soft-question

I am a highschool student some experience with Math Olympiads and I will be taking a Scientific Research class next year. I would like to ask for interesting Mathematics topics that I could consider - I have tried going online for possible research topics but I couldn't determine which was for my level.

I would like to also ask for resources that I could use for carrying out my research. I do not have access to programs such as PRIMES as I live outside the US.

Thank you.

Comment: The earlier MO question, ["Interesting and Accessible Topics in Graph Theory"](http://mathoverflow.net/q/64448/6094), may help.

Comment: @MatheMazier: You might want to consider learning a some programming using a [*Computer Algebra System*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_algebra_systems)

Comment: Be more specific, say, "what is your favorite theorem?"

Comment: You might browse the [Open Problems Garden](http://www.openproblemgarden.org/) and [The Open Problems Project](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/), both of which contain accessible research problems.

Comment: In addition to learning a CAS as suggested by Amzoti, another possibility is look at books in the reference section of [Experimental Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_mathematics) wiki page. They will have a lot of examples how to use numerical experiments and visualization to explore new ideas and ways to prove them.

Comment: Ask a friendly math professor from a university near you! Who knows -- someone might be willing to take you on for a summer project!

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of mathematical games for projects like these. They are fun, don't (necessarily) require advanced math -- I 've taught basic theory to groups 10 year olds -- and there are lots of open problems.  Check out Winning Ways, by Berlekamp, Conway, and Guy, and M. Albert, R. J. Nowakowski, D. Wolfe, Lessons in Play.  Here's a good website with a link to a list of open problems
http://www.mscs.dal.ca/~rjn/Site/Game_Theory.html

For motivation check out an award winning work by a (then) high school senior.
http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/INTEGERS/papers/dg3/dg3.Abstract.html

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few undergraduates who have done significant research in mathematics at your level. Even if you don't end up with a published paper, you will gain significant experience into what doing original research in mathematics means. Anyway, I think expecting to find a problem to work on yourself, rather than have a mentor suggest one (or several) to you, is unrealistic. Find a mentor (one of your professors maybe) who is willing to suggest a problem that you can deal with at your level, and (hopefully) give you ideas if you get stuck. On these websites (http://www2.edc.org/makingmath/mathproj.asp#rsproj ; http://wumath.wustl.edu/undergraduate/undergraduate-research/ideas)
you will find some interesting topics. As I said, you will be better off talking to a mentor, but on the first website I've listed, you will find some non-so-banal problems and also some useful hints and resources for tackling them, which are very useful if this is your first experience in research.